# How to close all Firefox sessions?

Tags: python

I am running a script where I need to close all open Firefox sessions. They need to be closed to see the final log on my appliance. How can I close them?

Comment: Oh right. Ok. Did you have something you wanted to ask, or did you just think we'd be interested?

Comment: @MikeW The question is in the title.

Comment: Maybe you could help us help you by writing what you have tried, what you expected to happen, and what did (or not) happen.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [psutil](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/) module. Code for your question:

```
import psutil

for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if 'firefox' in process.name:
        process.kill()
```

Comment: In its current form, this answer is better suited as a comment.  You should add more than simply a link--possibly an example usage of psutil's related functionality.

Comment: @Vulcan added an example.